# What happens when reading or writing concurrently without a mutex

Tags: go, concurrency, mutex, shared-memory, atomic

In Go, a `sync.Mutex` or `chan` is used to prevent concurrent access of shared objects. However, in some cases I am just interested in the "latest" value of a variable or field of an object.
Or I like to write a value and do not care if another go-routine overwrites it later or has just overwritten it before.

**Update:** TLDR; Just don't do this. It is not safe. Read the answers, comments, and linked documents!

**Update 2021:** The Go memory model is [going to be specified more thoroughly](https://github.com/golang/go/discussions/47141) and there are [three great articles](https://research.swtch.com/mm) by Russ Cox that will teach you more about the surprising effects of unsynchronized memory access. These articles summarize a lot of the below discussions and learnings.

Here are two variants `good` and `bad` of an example program, where both seem to produce "correct" output using the current Go runtime:

```golang
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

var bogus = flag.Bool("bogus", false, "use bogus code")

func pause() {
    time.Sleep(time.Duration(rand.Uint32()%100) * time.Millisecond)
}

func bad() {
    stop := time.After(100 * time.Millisecond)
    var name string

    // start some producers doing concurrent writes (DANGER!)
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        go func(i int) {
            pause()
            name = fmt.Sprintf("name = %d", i)
        }(i)
    }

    // start consumer that shows the current value every 10ms
    go func() {
        tick := time.Tick(10 * time.Millisecond)
        for {
            select {
            case <-stop:
                return
            case <-tick:
                fmt.Println("read:", name)
            }
        }
    }()

    <-stop
}

func good() {
    stop := time.After(100 * time.Millisecond)
    names := make(chan string, 10)

    // start some producers concurrently writing to a channel (GOOD!)
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        go func(i int) {
            pause()
            names <- fmt.Sprintf("name = %d", i)
        }(i)
    }

    // start consumer that shows the current value every 10ms
    go func() {
        tick := time.Tick(10 * time.Millisecond)
        var name string
        for {
            select {
            case name = <-names:
            case <-stop:
                return
            case <-tick:
                fmt.Println("read:", name)
            }
        }
    }()

    <-stop
}

func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    if *bogus {
        bad()
    } else {
        good()
    }
}
```

The expected output is as follows:

```
...
read: name = 3
read: name = 3
read: name = 5
read: name = 4
...
```

Any combination of `read:`  and `read: name=[0-9]` is correct output for this program. Receiving any other string as output would be an error.

When running this program with `go run --race bogus.go` it is safe.

However, `go run --race bogus.go -bogus` warns of the concurrent reads and writes.

For `map` types and when appending to slices I always need a mutex or a similar method of protection to avoid segfaults or unexpected behavior. However, reading and writing literals (atomic values) to variables or field values *seems* to be safe.

**Question:** Which Go data types can I safely read and safely write concurrently without a mutext and without producing segfaults and without reading garbage from memory?

Please **explain** why something is **safe or unsafe in Go** in your answer.

**Update**: I rewrote the example to better reflect the original code, where I had the the concurrent writes issue. The important leanings are already in the comments. I will accept an answer that summarizes these learnings with enough detail (esp. on the Go-runtime).

Comment: "seems to be safe" is not proof that it is safe. You always need synchronization for concurrent reads and writes of _any_ value.

Comment: That's why I am asking. If there are no safe cases then I wonder why the compiler does not enforce more syncing in general.

Comment: Because that was how go was designed. That would add a lot of unnecessary overhead if all reads and writes needed to be synchronized. Go provides simple concurrency primitives, and a really good race detector for testing.

Comment: @Juve That is a complete different question. Ask yourself: How could the compiler know that you are doing illegal stuff?

Comment: Nothing in the [memory model](https://golang.org/ref/mem) or language specification requires the compiler to assign a value to `name`.  One possible output is repeated lines of `name: `

Comment: I also found this: https://notes.shichao.io/gopl/ch9/ But it mainly talks out data races in slices and maps etc., for which I totally agree that you need sync them correctly. I was just wondering if I actually need to protect every string literal that may be used concurrently.

Comment: @CeriseLimón yes this would be a "correct" output as described in my question.

Comment: Data races are always data races, this isn't something specific to Go. Read: https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/blogs/benign-data-races-what-could-possibly-go-wrong.html

Comment: I assume you mean string variable and not string literal.  There's no guarantee that a string variable is read or written atomically.  A string value contains a pointer and a length.  With no synchronization, it's possible to see the previous pointer and new length or vice versa.   What's more, there's no guarantee that the pointer and length values are accessed atomically.

Comment: OK, then this means it is possible to read garbage even for strings. Do you have an example @CeriseLimón

Comment: Juve, please read the essay linked to by @JimB: it would tell you about so many interesting cases, I swear you'd be surprised ;-) I would also recommend to read [this](https://preshing.com/20130618/atomic-vs-non-atomic-operations/).

Comment: @Juve This discussion is fruitless. Your code **is** a prime example of a wrong program because it is racy. Please explain what is still unclear with "You must not mix unsynchronized reads and writes. Never. For all data types, for all syntax, really literally **never**.

Comment: …to continue the discussion, you could use function from the `sync/atomic` package to provide _atomicity_ of concurrent access to shared memory location (i.e. the lowest possible level of synchronization: the guarantee, that writes and reads come in a single piece while giving no guarantees about the ordering of such operations), but in either case please think about _maintainability_ of your code. Remember that [«software enggeneering is programming when you add time and other programmers»](https://research.swtch.com/vgo-eng). Your code must be understandable above anything else.

Comment: Thx, for all the links. So it depends on the current Go-runtime implementation on each specific architecture if my "correct" example will produce bogus or not. I will not rely on that and will always use `sync` and `sync/atomic` to protect my data (@Volker)

Comment: @Juve: you're missing the point. It does _not_ rely on the implementation to not produce bogus results, it's a data race, period. Different implementations may produce different results, but those results are always undefined and cannot be used.

Comment: @JimB I get all your points about data races and reproducible output. In my example I just cared about "allowed" output. The order and if some of the values would be skipped would not be relevant. But I now know the example is flawed, even for that purpose. Here is an abstract of what I was actually trying to do (now rewritten with channels): https://play.golang.org/p/wBmpwS2TfsJ Before using channels I was just setting the last `d.message` from the producing go-routines and then came here since I did not know if this was safe and why it would not be safe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> However, in some cases I am just interested in the latest value of a variable or field of an object.

Here is the fundamental problem: What does the word "latest" mean?

Suppoose that, mathematically speaking, we have a sequence of values *X<sub>i</sub>*, with *0 <= i < N*.  Then obviously *X<sub>j</sub>* is "later than" *X<sub>i</sub>* if *j > i*.  That's a nice simple definition of "latest" and is probably the one you want.

But when two separate CPUs within a single machine—including two goroutines in a Go program—are working *at the same time*, **time itself loses meaning**.  We cannot say whether i < j, i == j, or i > j.  So there is no correct definition for the word *latest*.

To solve this kind of problem, modern CPU hardware, and Go as a programming language, gives us certain *synchronization primitives*.  If CPUs A and B execute memory fence instructions, or synchronization instructions, or use whatever other hardware provisions exist, the CPUs (and/or some external hardware) will insert whatever is required for the notion of "time" to regain its meaning.  That is, if the CPU uses barrier instructions, we can say that a memory load or store that was executed *before* the barrier is a "before" and a memory load or store that is executed *after* the barrier is an "after".

(The actual implementation, in some modern hardware, consists of load and store buffers that can rearrange the order in which loads and stores go to memory.  The barrier instruction either synchronizes the buffers, or places an actual barrier in them, so that loads and stores cannot move across the barrier.  This particular concrete implementation gives an easy way to think about the problem, but isn't complete: you should think of time as simply *not existing* outside the hardware-provided synchronization, i.e., *all* loads from, and stores to, some location are happening simultaneously, rather than in some sequential order, except for these barriers.)

In any case, Go's `sync` package gives you a simple high level access method to these kinds of barriers.  Compiled code that executes before a mutex `Lock` call really does complete *before* the lock function returns, and the code that executes after the call really does not start until *after* the lock function returns.

Go's channels provide the same kinds of before/after time guarantees.

Go's `sync/atomic` package provides much lower level guarantees.  In general you should avoid this in favor of the higher level channel or `sync.Mutex` style guarantees.  (Edit to add note: You *could* use `sync/atomic`'s `Pointer` operations here, but not with the `string` type directly, as Go strings are actually implemented as a header containing two separate values: a pointer, and a length.  You could solve this with another layer of indirection, by updating a pointer that points to the `string` object.  But before you even consider doing that, you should benchmark the use of the language's preferred methods and verify that these are a problem, because code that works at the `sync/atomic` level is hard to write and hard to debug.)

Comment: With "latest" I meant the last written value that is then readable from the shared memory. The producer go-routine that wrote last to memory before the consumer reads the value would win the game. But for this to work reads and writes need to be atomic, i.e., you cannot write/read only "half a value" to/from memory. But as you stated above this can actually happen in Go, e.g., with strings, and this should result in unwanted string values. Do you have some links, where we can find more details/examples/issues about these non-atomic memory reads and writes in the Go-runtime?

Comment: **There is no "last", not at the hardware level.**  Time does not mean anything any more, not without barrier instructions. Due to write-behind write-buffering, the two CPUs can disagree as to what value was "last written"! See https://software.intel.com/content/dam/develop/public/us/en/documents/253668-sdm-vol-3a.pdf

Comment: When you use `sync/atomic`, which invokes the special compiler directives to use the special barrier instructions and make sure that write buffers are flushed, etc., *then* there is a "last". But when you don't, there just isn't. The mutex package builds on `sync/atomic` and hides the remaining special cases.

Comment: Ugh, it looks like Intel have moved the documentation again (it was in a different link that suggested the link I posted this time). I have to find where they have put it.

Comment: Ah, no, that link is OK. See section 8.2 (especially 8.2.2 and subsequent sections) on temporality in x86 multi-cpu systems; there are nontemporal store instructions, which the compiler may choose to use in various cases. Note that x86 hardware is one of the more forgiving, too, as the underlying hardware provides a pretty strong memory ordering model. Other CPUs that Go builds for use weaker ordering.

Comment: In any case, it's also important to be sure that the *compiler* does not re-order instructions. This is less of an issue with current Go compilers than with current C/C++/similar compilers, but the *language itself* makes no such guarantee unless you use the provided synchronization primitives.

Comment: I read the Intel doc sections on reordering and was wondering if integers on Intel are "safe" (from bogus values) and if anything else that cannot be stored using one `mov` would be "not safe". I wrote a [demo](https://github.com/ubntc/go-cli/tree/master/playground/corruption) that shows no integer errors on Intel but even crashes on ARM. After learning so much about memory and Go in the present discussions I now understand why Volker posted such a bold answer. However I like good explanations and will instead accept yours. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Even Intel hardware will "tear" a read or write into two separate read/write ops if it straddles a cache line or page boundary. Normal operation in Go won't have unaligned reads or writes, fortunately. (But, the non-temporal store operators bypass the normal cache coherency mechanisms.)

Comment: While, as usually, your answer is very good, I'd also point out that unsynchronized access to variables which _look "naturlly atomic"_ on a given hardware — such as `int64`s on `amd64` is not required to happen atomically. One might start with [this piece](https://preshing.com/20130618/atomic-vs-non-atomic-operations/).

Comment: @kostix: yes, that's an example of a compiler-induced torn read or write (vs a hardware-induced one). When using a compiler to implement the hardware's provided atomicity, one must verify that the compiler is actually generating the desired instructions. :-) In gcc we mostly use `asm volatile` constructs for this sort of thing. Go of course lacks this kind of fiddly control, which means sometimes the entire package, or at least some critical function, is in assembly.

Answer (score 4):

> Which Go data types can I safely read and safely write concurrently without a mutext and without producing segfaults and without reading garbage from memory?

None.

It really is that simple: You cannot, under no circumstance whatsoever, read and write concurrently to anything in Go.

(Btw: Your "correct" program is not correct, it is racy and even if you get rid of the race condition it would not deterministically produce the output.)

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use channels

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {

    var wg sync.WaitGroup // wait group to close channel
    var buffer int = 1    // buffer of the channel

    // channel to get the share data
    cName := make(chan string, buffer)
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        wg.Add(1) // add to wait group
        go func(i int) {
            cName <- fmt.Sprintf("name = %d", i)
            wg.Done() // decrease wait group.
        }(i)

    }

    go func() {
        wg.Wait() // wait of wait group to be 0
        close(cName) // close the channel
    }()

    // process all the data
    for n := range cName {
        println("read:", n)
    }

}
```

The above code returns the following output

```
read: name = 0
read: name = 5
read: name = 1
read: name = 2
read: name = 3
read: name = 4
read: name = 7
read: name = 6
read: name = 8
read: name = 9
```

https://play.golang.org/p/R4n9ssPMOeS

[Article about channels](https://golangbot.com/channels/)

Comment: Yes channels would be the best solution: I also just rewrote it: https://play.golang.org/p/RByVuPksc8c with channels.

Comment: rather than using time.Sleep(), use sync.WaitGroups.