# is access to single variable from routines integrity safe?

Tags: go

Given such a code:

```
type Test struct {
    V int
}

func (t *Test) t() {
    t.V += 1
}

func main() {

    t := Test{}
    for i := 1; i <= 1000000; i++ {
        go t.t()
    }

    for {
        fmt.Println(t.V)
        time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
    }
}
```

I hope it is clear, why do I do this test. And the result is never 1000000. It always prints number less than 1000000.. So, only `go channels` can I use to solve it ?

Why don't I have 1000000 in result ? How to get 1000000 ?

Comment: You have a classic race condition, which you seem to know. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: Your question is not clear. If you are asking whether all data in Go is automatically atomic, it isn't. You need to use a mutex to prevent data races.

Comment: You are trying to communicate by sharing. To do this you must insert some kind of mutual exclusion. Go provides methods to share by communicating, which do not require that you insert your own mutual exclusion. The choice is yours: to communicate by sharing, or to share by communicating.

Comment: This topic has been beaten to death already but you might start with [this very recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61914041/720999) and the sheer discussions in comments which ensued; pay close attenton to the links to external materials provided. The answer is also good.

Answer (score 2):

> is access to single variable from routines integrity safe?

No. Everything that is racy is not safe. Under no circumstances. Not if is a single variable, not if accessed by an odd number of goroutines and not on Mondays. Never.

Comment: So only channels can be solution to get 1000000 ?

Comment: There are many solutions to get 1000000, that don't involve channels. The most obvious one is to remove the word `go` from your code. Another is to use a mutex, as suggested by @marc in his comment above. But there are others as well.

Comment: @Mikael No any non-racy code can give you right answers. It does not matter if you make your code unracy by removing concurrency, or by proper synchronisation (and in which case you are free to use any one you like, channels, mutexes, lock free algorithms, atomic operations....).